# Retrofit OkHttp HttpLoggingInterceptor show correctly response, but retrofit show not correctly response

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to upload a photo to the server.
My problem is that I can not get a link to this picture, which the server returns to me.

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    public static Retrofit createService(
            String username, String password) {
        String authToken = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        return createService(authToken);
    }

    public static Retrofit createService(final String authToken) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken))
            interceptor =    new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);




        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConstant.BASE_URL+"/")
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


    }

    public static RetroInterface getApiServices(String user_name, String passowrd) {
        return createService(user_name, passowrd).create(RetroInterface.class);
    }
}
```

RetroInterface.java

```
....
@Multipart
@POST("parents/profile/images")
Call<String>
uploadParentProfilePicture2(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
....
```

Profile.java

```
....
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
        RetroInterface retroInterface = RetrofitClient.getApiServices(getEmail(), getPassword());
        Call<String> call = retroInterface.uploadParentProfilePicture(filePart);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                    Log.d("ldsfjjlk", "response: " + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ldsfjjlk", "Throwable: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
....
```

HttpLoggingInterceptor response :

```
"parents/654/profile/images/1530979485020.jpg"
```

It is right!

My log:

```
"parents"
```

What is this?

Something wrong with Retrofit?

Also I tried to replace
`Call<String>` to `Call<ResponseBody>` but:
`response.body.string() == null`
What did I miss?

Comment: can you debug and see `response` what it has ?

Comment: @AjayS 
Log.d("ldsfjjlk", "response: " + response.body()) = "parents";   

HtppLoggingInterceptor:
https://justpaste.it/6dymu

Comment: it has to do with your converter factory

Comment: @masoudvali OK. But what exactly is wrong with the converter factory?